# Why do i always get The property or field has not been initialized?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

Hello i try to populate an Array with specific fields. But i always get: `The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.` I am on Sharepoint 2013 and i use the internal names from sharepoint. I assume that there is something wrong with my Caml Query.

Here is the Code i use:

```
 function retrieveListItems(siteUrl) {

        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('MatrixFiles');

        var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><ViewFields><FieldRef Name="LinkFilename" /><FieldRef Name="WebCountry" /><FieldRef Name="WebDepartment" /><FieldRef Name="FileLeafRef" /></ViewFields><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="LinkFilename" /></OrderBy></Query></View>');
        this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

        clientContext.load(collListItem);

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

    }
```

And here the other part with the array:

```
function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

    var listItemInfo = '';
    var array = [];

    var listItemEnumerator = this.collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        console.log(oListItem);

        array.push(oListItem);



    }

    alert(oListItem.get_item('LinkFilename'));


}
```

The strange thing is the array gets filled with SPListItems but when i try to use a specific field in an alert the error happens. No clue why....

Any help would be great and thx for your Time.

BTW i used the [SP Caml Query helper](https://spcamlqueryhelper.codeplex.com/) for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using **FileLeafRef**. LinkFilename is a computed field which does not work.

[msdn - Not able to search list using LinkFileName](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ff4d255d-684f-4388-b1df-e7f1cbb08d4d/not-able-to-search-list-using-linkfilename?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy)

Answer (score 1):

I imagine this error is occurring because the sp.js script has not been loaded.

Try:

```
  //Insert this right after your opening script tag
   ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveListItems, "sp.js");

   //then your function as written above   
   function retrieveListItems(siteUrl) { etc...};
```

Also this answer may be helpful: [SharePoint 2013 add javascript after whole page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16936250/sharepoint-2013-add-javascript-after-whole-page-load)